# How do I raise a custom exception with google cloud endpoints in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

So I can see in the docs for Python you can just go:

```
raise endpoints.NotFoundException(message)
```

(https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions)

so in Java I tried:

```
resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Event has no attendee!");
```

when I do this in Java I get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]"
 }
}
```

How do I do this properly? Thanks!

Comment: I might have it, I tried: BadRequestException new BadRequestException("Company is null!"); and then did a throw on this exception, seems to return a custom message that I can parse in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above, this worked great for what I needed.